# How should I handle a multiple scenes project?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm trying to make this game using the approach of multiple scenes to make things more modular.

In my actual case I have an "Initialization" scene which holds some global state objects and the one to control the state machine of all the scenes in the game.

As for the other scenes, for now I divided them just in two: the base scenes (which for now contains everything besides UI) and its UI scenes (which basically have a `Canvas` and all the UI elements and UI-related scripts).

The confusion in my mind is simple though: as I tried to make the UI scenes as modular and independent as possible, there are a lot of points of interactions between the base scene and its UI scene.

For the sake of illustrating this question please take this problem I'm facing right now: I have camera animations that should be played as a response to user inputs to the UI (like the click of a button should trigger a specific camera animation). Thing is: that camera is not in the UI scene. The way I'm resolving this problem right now is creating a `ScriptableObject` which holds events for important actions triggered in the UI scene that are fired in the UI scene and subscribed in any other place. The same can occur in the opposite direction: the UI scene need to react to many actions that happens in other scenes.

Considering that the "camera animation" problem I explained above can happen with many other objects, if **there is not a better way to handle that** wouldn't splitting a game into multiple scenes be just too much of work just for the benefit of modularity? And by that I also asks: am I handling this problem the right way?

Comment: Your question sounds a bit opinion-based. In my opinion multiple scenes in Unity make - due to the not trivial cross scene references - more things complicated than it solves. In my eyes there is no big gain in having multiple scenes in your use case. If you want modularity I would rather use module prefabs you can edit individually without having to touch the main scene. Then you could have one central app controller which connects all these individual modules so they can interact. Scenes only make sense if you actually load and unload them

Comment: @derHugo thanks for the feedback. Do you happen to know a better place to ask those kind of questions? Each and every question I ask here that are slightly more directed towards software architecture (which are not so clear objective) I get downvotes and barely someone gives any feedback whatsoever.

Comment: Also valid to point that unity forums or the gamedev of stackexchange are not that active, they are more likely dead communities...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep things consistent between scenes, there are a few ways to do it.

PlayerPrefs lets you keep variables consistent, I don't need to do a whole tutorial here, look it up.

DontDestroyOnLoad lets you take an object and make it consistent throughout the whole game. If you want, you can use DontDestroyOnLoad on one of your cameras and just delete the others in the other scenes if you want to keep a consistent camera.

Comment: I don't think these are good approaches as it hides dependency between scenes. Either using the PlayerPrefs and the DontDestroyOnLoads you will be creating global state. I'm looking for a proper way to do that. Thanks for the answer anyway though!